# Projection of a matrix onto a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-calculus

Okay, this is something that is bothering me. If $v$ is a vector on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and we want to project it onto some subspace, say, $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$, we look for a projection matrix $P$ and the projection is given by $Pv$.

Is it possible to project *matrices* as well? If so, suppose I want to project a matrix $M$ onto some vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Is this projection given by $PM$ or $PMP$? I realized I'm getting confused about this.

As a direct application of what I'm asking; let $M$ and $N$ two matrices. Suppose $P$ projects $N$ to zero. Should this imply $PNP = 0$ or simply $PN = 0$? In this case, is $PM$ (or, $PMP$) the projection of $M$ onto the same subspace?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by projection. Within the *space* of matrices (ex: $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$), you can project onto a subspace just as in a vector space. Here the projector operator would be a linear transformation on matrices.

What you're describing is old fashioned matrix multiplication. $PM$ first applies $M$ to the vector and then projects the result. $MP$ first *projects* the vector and then applies the matrix $M$.

Comment: @Vercingetorix thanks for your comment! So, taking my example, neither $PM$ or $PMP$ projects $M$? I mean, there is no such interpretation? What would be the correct form of projecting a matrix then?

Comment: As @Vercingetorix said, it depends on what you mean by “projection”. A matrix/linear operator $P : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is a *projection* iff $P^2 = P$, and it *projects* vectors onto the image. If you want to project a matrix, what does that mean for you?

Comment: If $P$ projects $N$ to $0$, to me, that sounds like saying $PN = 0$, i.e. the image of $N$ lies in the null space of $P$. But there are many applications of projection for specific matrices, e.g. given a matrix $M$, $\mathbb R^n$ decomposes orthogonally into the null space and row space, and you might want to project onto the row space; that’s a classical application of projections (since the row space and column space are isomorphic).

Comment: @InMathweTrust I am not aware of any standard interpretation of the phrase "projecting a matrix". However, the [compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_(functional_analysis)) of a matrix is similar to your idea of computing $PMP$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann very interesting comment! Thanks again! But, to be sincere, the idea seems exactly the same as taking $PMP$. Or isn't it?

Comment: @BenGrossmann let me rephrase my question. The wikipedia article says we should take $P_{K}T|_{K}$,where $P_{K}$ is the orthogonal projection $P_{K}: H \to K$ and $T$ the linear operator. If $T$ is the matrix of my post $T=M$, I could take $P_{K} = P$, the matrix defined by $PN = 0$, right? But how to properly restrict the product $PM$ to a subspace? I mean, can I do it by multiplying by another matrix or something like that?

Comment: @InMathweTrust If $U$ is a matrix with orthonormal columns, then a compression of the matrix $M$ is a matrix of the form $U^TMU$. In a sense, this matrix corresponds to your version of a projection: $P = UU^T$ is a projection onto the column space of $U$, and there is a corrspondence between the matrices $PMP = U(U^TMU)U^T$ and $U^TMU$.